# Show that $A, B \in L(V)$ Are Similar

Tags: linear-algebra

The following question comes from Halmos' FDVS, page 95.  I am okay with the $(\rightarrow)$ part, but I am not 100% sure with the converse.  Specifically, can I "neatly" stack the vectors in the bases, $\{x_i\}$ and $\{y_i\}$, of $V$ like I did below?  In each basis, I grouped every vector generating the null-space to one side.

Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are linear transformations (on the same finite-dimensional vector space) such that $A^2 = A$ and $B^2 = B$.  Is it true that $A$ and $B$ are similar $\leftrightarrow$ dim$R(A)$ = dim$R(B)$?

$(\rightarrow)$  Let $T$ be the invertible transformation such that $A = T^{-1}BT$. dim$R(A)$ = dim$R(T^{-1}BT)$ = dim$R(BT) \le$ dim$R(B)$. The equality comes from the fact that $T$ is isomorphic.  Similary, dim$R(B)$ = dim$R(TAT^{-1})$ = dim$R(AT^{-1}) \le$ dim$R(A)$.  So, dim$R(A)$ = dim$R(B)$.

$(\leftarrow)$  Since $V$ is finite-dimensional, by the rank-nullity theorem and the premise that dim$R(A)$ = dim$R(B)$, we have dim$N(A)$ = dim$N(B)$.  Now, let $\{x_1, x_2 ...x_m\}$ be a basis of $N(A)$ and extend it to $\{x_1, x_2 ... x_m, x_{m+1} ... x_n\}$, basis of V.  Likewise, let $\{y_1, y_2 ...y_m\}$ be a basis of $N(B)$ and extend it to $\{y_1, y_2 ... y_m, y_{m+1} ... y_n\}$, basis of V.  Let $T \in L(V)$ be defined by $T(x_i) = y_i$ for all $i = 1$ to $n$.  I already proved in another question that T is isomorphic and therefore invertible.

Take $x \in N(A)$; $x = \sum_{i = 1}^m a_ix_i$.  $T^{-1}BTx = \sum_{i = 1}^m a_iT^{-1}BTx_i = 0$.  So $N(A) \subset N(T^{-1}BT)$.  Because the two sets have the same dimension, they are equal, and $Ax = 0 = T^{-1}BTx$. 
Now, take $x \in $ span$\{x_{m+1} ... x_n\}$; $Ax = x = \sum_{i = m+1}^n a_ix_i = \sum_{i = m+1}^n a_iT^{-1}BTx_i = T^{-1}BTx$.  So in the case where $x \notin N(A)$, $Ax = T^{-1}BTx$ also.  As a result, $A = T^{-1}BT$.

Answer (score 0):

$A^2 = A$ and $B^2 = B$ implies the eigenvalues of the matrices associated with $A$ and $B$ are either $0$ or $1$.  (Consider that $x^2-x=0$ has only the roots $0$ and $1$.)  The dimension of the nullspace of each is the count of $0$ eigenvalues.  They are therefore similar if they have the same number of $0$ eigenvalues.